# Fixing a Question Ban

Tags: support, ban, on-hold

I received a question ban yesterday (which I deserved). I thought that Stack Overflow was a tech question and answer site rather than just coding.

I want to un-ban my account but I'm not sure how. I completely rewrote the question (completely different subject now and I good question that I need help with), but how do I get un-banned?

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18068074/revisions

Comment: That's still not a great question. If you need help with code that you've written, you need to provide that code, preferably as a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: are you question-banned (can't ask new questions) or did your question get put on hold? What to do is different in each case

Comment: I rolled back that edit; you completely invalidated the existing answer. Please do NOT rewrite a post for totally different questions. You'll have to work on some of the other 46 questions.

Comment: @KateGregory I'm on question ban.

Comment: @Arjan Ok, I see the change. Where should I go from here? The original question doesn't belong on stackoverflow

Comment: then I'm puzzled why you say "the question" - you've asked almost 50, fix them all or at least a lot of them not just one

Comment: Don't just focus on one question. Look at all your questions. Any upvotes due to improvements are welcome.

Comment: You're not currently blocked.  Happy hunting.